# Generic way of adding SqlParameter to the SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection, sqlparameter

We have a legacy C# application where we have a lot of inline SQL queries that are being executed against the input that was passed by the user. So, obviously SQL injection came into the picture. Now we want to fix it but the thing is we want to go with minimalistic approach. Not touching to much code. So ORM and stored procedures are kind of out of the equation for us.

We have to update every inline statement to make use of SQL parameterization approach. However, what I am looking for is may be if there is a generic way of doing it. Like send the query to a method and generate the `SqlParameter` array dynamically.

By query I mean literally the query whenever I can without using the conventional @

```
Select * 
From table 
Where id = 1 and name = 'Sean'  and            
location like  '%cali'
```

To something like this

```
List<Sqlparameters> params = new 
List<Sqlparameters>() 

var query = Select * from table where id = @v1 and name =@v2 and location like @v3

params.Add("v1", 1)
params.Add("v2",  'Sean')
params.Add("v3","%cali")
```

Update

Now, I have a method which does this for me. This will take the sql text like this

```
var sql = "select * from merchants where merchantID={" + Request["merchantid"] +"}"
```

Method

```
Public command Method(string query) 
{
var cmd =new Command();
cmd.text="";
cmd.params=new List<SqlParameter>() ;


// code to trasform the query. Identify values based on the special char '{'. Dynamically adds placeholder variables and values into an array

cmd.text="select * from merchants where merchantID=@variable1

//Loops through variables and adds values
// to parameters 

cmd.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("variable1",  value1);

return cmd;

}
```

Comment: Sure there is, but can you post an example of one of your more complex SQL queries?

Comment: Use Dapper.  It makes things so much easier.

Comment: Can you provide a more elaborate example, showing all types of parameters you are dealing with? Your example shows only a parameter of type int. I guess that you also have parameters of type string and date (at least).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias updated.

Comment: These queries are static strings stored inside the application code, or are generated dynamically and include input from users? In the later case it won't do any good to parameterize the queries. It would only lead to the parameterization of the SQL injection attacks!

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias . They are generated dynamically based on the user input. Can you explain what you meant by your last sentence?

Comment: Sure. The point of SQL parameterization is to prevent attackers from forming malicious queries by ensuring that their input will be parsed as literal data, and not as SQL syntax. It is harmless to store the string "DROP TABLE Users" in a record in the database, but it is catastrophic if the same string is executed as SQL command by the RDBMS engine. In your case the injection has already been performed at this stage, and parameterizing will not make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This raised another question for me on how adding parameter by parameter and doing it generic way differs. I will try to update the question.

Comment: In case you have an urgent need to raise some kind of defense against SQL injection attacks, and not being 100% protected is acceptable, I would suggest going the route of black-listing keywords associated with the most dangerous types of attacks. Keywords like DROP, EXEC, EXECUTE, sysobjects, syscolumns etc, and also UPDATE and DELETE not in the start of the query. It is not safe, and it creates a false sense of security, but it is better than nothing. This technique is so outdated that you will find more easily such code for ASP/VBScript than for modern languages though.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias uodated with what I did. Will this still be vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Ι can't give a definitive answer because the code that transforms the query is not shown. If the value of `Request["merchantid"]` becomes directly the value of the `SqlParameter` then it is safe. If it is first embedded in the SQL, and then extracted and replaced with a parameter, then it is not safe. An attacker could start with a closing delimiter `}`, and then proceed with the injection code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Ok i see what you are saying here. The code will try to find the parentheses and will extract the values initially to put them into a list. Let's say there are three where conditions then there will be three corresponding values in the list. We will loop through each value and add them as sqlparameter. So from what you say i guess this can still cause injection. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. If you allow the user to inject his code without parameterizing his input up front, you may end up with an SQL command like this: `select * from merchants where merchantID={141};DROP TABLE USERS;--{}`. At this point it will be too late to clean up his injection by parameterizing the values inside the braces.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a quick generic method that will do what you want. It uses Regular Expressions to find all the parameters (they must be prefixed with the @ character)

```
    // This will build a SqlCommand from query text, and build SqlParameters
    // foreach "@Param" in the query e.g. WHERE Name = @Name and Date = @Date
    private SqlCommand GenerateSqlCommand(string queryText, params object[] paramValues)
    {
        // Build SqlCommand
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryText);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        // Find all instances of @Param sql parameter names in the query
        var matches = Regex.Matches(queryText, @"[@#]\w+");
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i ++)
        {
            // Add this parameter to the command with the value from the paramValues
            // Parameters passed into the method must be in order 
            // E.g. if the Query is "SELECT * FROM TABLE where Name = @Name and Date = @Date
            // then paramValues must be { 'My Name', '04-24-2019' }
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(matches[i].Value, paramValues[i]);
        }

        // Return command
        return sqlCommand;
    }
```

You can use this to build your SQL Command using the params object[] to pass in the values for each parameter in the query. An example of usage is:

```
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            var param1 = "This is a parameter";
            var param2 = "04/23/2019";
            var param3 = 2;

            using (var comm = GenerateSqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username and Date = @Date and Id = @Id", param1, param2, param3))
                {
                comm.Connection = conn;
                using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // TODO: handle the results
                        reader.GetString(0);
                        reader.GetInt32(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jon. Where is the @ prefix being added?

Comment: Well I presume your SQL query will have these already prefixed in the parameters. Example of a query would be "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username and Active = @Active"

Comment: In order to use SqlCommand with parameters you must have the parameters in your query prefixed with @

Comment: I updated the answer to include a more clear example of a SQL query text

Comment: I think your regex will match only the `@`, but not the rest of the variable name.

Comment: @Amy I'm terrible with Regex, I was going off this https://www.mpi.nl/corpus/html/trova/ch01s04.html  \bsa all words starting with sa

Comment: @Amy you were right, I fixed the regular expression to @"[@#]\w+"

Comment: Jon Thanks for the update. May be I haven't made my question clear. I want to know if I can eliminate the need for parameters. I guess this is what I may end up doing but what I actually wanted to know is not to pass the parameters at all. If you look at my original query I am not using the parameters at all. I want the method to take care of that. Detect how many of such variables exists may be based on a special character and generate the parameters

Comment: That's exactly what my code does. It will detect all the parameters in the query, e.g. in your example "Select * from table where id = @somename" it will detect @somename, add this as a SqlParameter to the SqlCommand and set the value to the value you provide in paramValues. So you would call GenerateSqlCommand("Select * from table where id = @somename", 1);

Answer (score 0):

What @Jon wrote is a good solution, but just in case you want more. There is an ORM library i build that could handle almost all those possible senario.

[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityWorker.Core/)

[CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1222424/EntityWorker-Core-An-Alternative-to-Entity-Framewo)

[Github](https://github.com/AlenToma/EntityWorker.Core)

Now you could simple execute an sql like this instead.

```
var cmd = rep.GetSqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = String[admin]");
```

`String[..]` `Date[..] and Guid[..]` will be converted to a parameter later on.
You could also add parameter manually to, read the documentation to understand more